# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bookscraper'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am following a tutorial for a website scraper using python. I am attempting to run some code that will run the the scraped data through an itemizer (scrapy.item). When I run the code I have to import a class I created on another .py file. However, python is not able to recognize the file that it's in as a module.

My file directory

```
PYTHONSCRAPING
-bookscraper
  -bookscraper
   -spiders
    -bookspider.py
   -items.py
   -middlewares.py
   -pipelines.py
   -settings.py
```

BookItem class code located in items.py. I have code in bookspider.py that will collect the data and run it through this code to assign values to each piece of data.

```
  class BookItem(scrapy.Item):
        url = scrapy.Field()
        title = scrapy.Field()
        upc = scrapy.Field()
        product_type = scrapy.Field()
        price_excl_tax = scrapy.Field()
        price_incl_tax = scrapy.Field()
        tax = scrapy.Field()
        availability = scrapy.Field()
        num_reviews = scrapy.Field()
        stars = scrapy.Field()
        category = scrapy.Field()
        description = scrapy.Field()
        price = scrapy.Field()
```

I am trying to import the class above into my bookspiders.py file

```
from bookscraper.items import BookItem
```

I need to import BookItem because I have code located in bookspider.py that is being used to collected data from the websites HTML code.

```
def parse_book_page(self, response):
        table_rows = response.css('table tr')
        book_item = BookItem() #links code to items in items.py
        
        book_item['url'] = response.url,
        book_item['title'] = response.css('.product_main h1::text').get(),
        book_item['upc'] = table_rows[0].css('td ::text').get(),
        book_item['product_type'] = table_rows[1].css('td ::text').get(),
        book_item['price_excl_tax'] = table_rows[2].css('td ::text').get(),
        book_item['price_incl_tax'] = table_rows[3].css('td ::text').get(),
        book_item['tax'] = table_rows[4].css('td ::text').get(),
        book_item['availablitiy'] = table_rows[5].css('td ::text').get(),
        book_item['num_reviews'] = table_rows[6].css('td ::text').get(),
        book_item['stars'] = response.css('p.star-rating').attrib['class'],
        book_item['category'] = response.xpath("//ul[@class='breadcrumb']/li[@class='active']/preceding-sibling::li[1]/a/text()").get(),
        book_item['description'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='product_description']/following-sibling::p/text()").get(),
        book_item['price'] = response.css('p.price_color ::text').get(),
        yield book_item
```

However, when I try to import BookItems it comes back with this error

```
(venv) (base) Tomass-MBP:bookscraper fullsnack$ /Users/fullsnack/Desktop/HelloWorld/PythonScraping/venv/bin/python /Users/fullsnack/Desktop/HelloWorld/PythonScraping/bookscraper/bookscraper/spiders/bookspider.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fullsnack/Desktop/HelloWorld/PythonScraping/bookscraper/bookscraper/spiders/bookspider.py", line 38, in <module>
    from bookscraper.items import BookItem #imports the items from item.py so that python can recognize when the items in the def parse_book_pages() 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bookscraper'
```

I am on python version 3.9.13 and I am also using a virtual environment when coding within my file.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

From Python 3.3, referencing or importing a module in the parent directory is not allowed.

You could get around this by hacks with sys.path and PYTHONPATH, but I would advise against it, seeing your project, it is most definitely not something you would want to do.

Instead, you probably want to run a script from the root of your project, then the imports of modules in packages will work.

By the way, for a folder to be a Python package (which allows imports), it must contain a file named __init__.py. It can be empty, and often is (good practice in many cases), but is has to be there.

As you are using scrapy, instead of executing the spider script (which is in child directory and without hack wont be able to import anything), run the scrapy runner from the parent directory. As per the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html):

```
scrapy crawl <spider-name>
```

where spider name is the name field of your spider in booksspider.py. Name in the field name, not the name of the class.

Or, alternatively, execute a different script from the bookscraper directory (package with __init__.py), the you can import from subpackage.